Generic object Copy to an other object
I want to make a generic copy, not a clone. I don't have much knowledge and some parts of the code are difficult for me to do.
I want to copy a model called ItemsDto to ItemsModel.
Here is the code:
ItemsDto:
public class ItemsDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public List<ItemDto> Items { get; set; } = [];
  public ItemDto Item { get; set; } = new ItemDto();
  public List<string> Infos { get; set; } = [];
}

ItemDto:
public class ItemDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Item { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

ItemsModel:
public partial class ItemsModel: BaseViewModel
{
  [ObservableProperty] private int _id;
  [ObservableProperty] private List<ItemModel> _items = [];
  [ObservableProperty] private ItemModel _item = new ItemModel();
  [ObservableProperty] private List<string> _infos = [];
}

ItemModel:
public partial class ItemModel: BaseModel
{
  [ObservableProperty] private int _id;
  [ObservableProperty] private string _item = string. Empty;
}

Generic Copy:
    public static TTarget? Copy<TTarget, TSource>(TSource? source)
    {
      var target = (TTarget?)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TTarget));

      if (source == null || target == null) return default;

      foreach (var targetProperty in target.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        var sourceProperty = source.GetType().GetProperty(targetProperty.Name);
        if (sourceProperty == null) return target;

        var sourceValues = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null);
        if (sourceValues == null) continue;

        // copy identical objects
        if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == targetProperty.PropertyType)
        {
            targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceValues);
        }
        
        // copy object
        if (sourceProperty.PropertyType.Name != targetProperty.PropertyType.Name)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in targetProperty.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var sProperty = sourceValues.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);

                if (sProperty == null) continue;
                propertyInfo.SetValue(target, sourceValues);
            }
        }
        // copy list of object
        else if (sourceProperty.PropertyType.Name.Contains("List`1"))
        {
            foreach (var sourceValue in (IEnumerable)sourceValues)
            {
                foreach (var propertyInfo in targetProperty.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var sProperty = sourceValues.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);

                    if (sProperty == null) continue;
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(target, sourceValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return target;
 }

So far, for public int Id { get; set; } and public List<string> Infos { get; set; } = []; in the description "copy identical objects" works.
I can't make it work for public List<ItemDto> Items { get; set; } = []; and public ItemDto Item { get; set; } = new ItemDto(); because the code is incorrect in the description "copy object" and "copy list of object"

You could have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net, especially this answer, which might give you some ideas.

Since a ItemsDto can contain ItemsDto(s) is this recursive and you need to maintain that?

@TimSchmelter it looks to me that it's for the same model public static T DeepClone<T>(this T obj) and not for a different model public static TTarget? Copy<TTarget, TSource>(TSource? source)

@JBD: sure, otherwise it would be a duplicate question. However, i'd recommend using AutoMapper

@Ralf yes, because I'm trying to get all possible cases

Then you need a definition of what is "same" object. In your example it might be the reference or the Id. You might need a proper IEquatable implementation in your source objects or fall back to reference equals. Either way you need to maintain a proper list of what was already mapped and reuse that. Typical Object mapper solutions should have that build in.

Object mapping is a solved problem. Why reinvent the wheel? => Mapster, AutoMapper , ...

@Fildor it's MVVM in Maui, so it's seen as public

Ah, so [ObservableProperty] does some magic, I see.

what is the distinction between "copy" and "clone"?

@Jason Does the clone copy data to an already instantiated object? i.e. itemsDto to ItemsModel.

Clone and Copy are just words mostly taken as synonym as what they mean depends on who is talking. Here it doesn't matter to much as both describe ending up in the same type as the source (that is how they are understood mostly). Best wording describing what you want is Mapping.
